# Create a custom Transformer in PySpark ML

Tags: python, apache-spark, nltk, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am new to Spark SQL DataFrames and ML on them (PySpark). 
How can I create a custom tokenizer, which for example removes stop words and uses some libraries from [nltk](/questions/tagged/nltk)? Can I extend the default one?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

> Can I extend the default one?

Not really. Default `Tokenizer` is a subclass of `pyspark.ml.wrapper.JavaTransformer` and, same as other transfromers and estimators from `pyspark.ml.feature`, delegates actual processing to its Scala counterpart. Since you want to use Python you should extend `pyspark.ml.pipeline.Transformer` directly.

```
import nltk

from pyspark import keyword_only  ## < 2.0 -> pyspark.ml.util.keyword_only
from pyspark.ml import Transformer
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param, Params, TypeConverters
# Available in PySpark >= 2.3.0 
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable  
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

class NLTKWordPunctTokenizer(
        Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol,
        # Credits https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467470
        # by https://stackoverflow.com/users/234944/benjamin-manns
        DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):

    stopwords = Param(Params._dummy(), "stopwords", "stopwords",
                      typeConverter=TypeConverters.toListString)


    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, stopwords=None):
        super(NLTKWordPunctTokenizer, self).__init__()
        self.stopwords = Param(self, "stopwords", "")
        self._setDefault(stopwords=[])
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None, stopwords=None):
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def setStopwords(self, value):
        return self._set(stopwords=list(value))

    def getStopwords(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.stopwords)

    # Required in Spark >= 3.0
    def setInputCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`inputCol`.
        """
        return self._set(inputCol=value)

    # Required in Spark >= 3.0
    def setOutputCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`outputCol`.
        """
        return self._set(outputCol=value)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        stopwords = set(self.getStopwords())

        def f(s):
            tokens = nltk.tokenize.wordpunct_tokenize(s)
            return [t for t in tokens if t.lower() not in stopwords]

        t = ArrayType(StringType())
        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]
        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(f, t)(in_col))
```

Example usage (data from [ML - Features](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#tokenizer)):

```
sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame([
  (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
  (0, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
  (1, "Logistic regression models are neat")
], ["label", "sentence"])

tokenizer = NLTKWordPunctTokenizer(
    inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words",  
    stopwords=nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

tokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame).show()
```

For custom Python `Estimator` see [How to Roll a Custom Estimator in PySpark mllib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37270446/1560062)

⚠ This answer depends on internal API and is compatible with Spark 2.0.3, 2.1.1, 2.2.0 or later ([SPARK-19348](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19348)). For code compatible with previous Spark versions please see [revision 8](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32337101/8).

Comment: @zero323 I think I have done it in an answer to this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399399/serialize-a-custom-transformer-using-python-to-be-used-within-a-pyspark-ml-pipel/44377489#44377489

Comment: has the API been updated? it seems pretty cumbersome rather than just writing init and _transform one needs to do all that ._set stuff?