# How to create a custom Estimator in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to build a simple custom `Estimator` in PySpark MLlib. I have [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml/32337101?noredirect=1#comment62052435_32337101) that it is possible to write a custom Transformer but I am not sure how to do it on an `Estimator`. I also don't understand what `@keyword_only` does and why do I need so many setters and getters. Scikit-learn seem to have a proper document for custom models ([see here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator)) but PySpark doesn't.

Pseudo code of an example model:

```
class NormalDeviation():
    def __init__(self, threshold = 3):
    def fit(x, y=None):
       self.model = {'mean': x.mean(), 'std': x.std()]
    def predict(x):
       return ((x-self.model['mean']) > self.threshold * self.model['std'])
    def decision_function(x): # does ml-lib support this?
```

Answer (score 28):

Generally speaking there is no documentation because as for Spark 1.6 / 2.0 most of the related API is not intended to be public. It should change in Spark 2.1.0 (see [SPARK-7146](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7146)).

API is relatively complex because it has to follow specific conventions in order to make given `Transformer` or `Estimator` compatible with `Pipeline` API. Some of these methods may be required for features like reading and writing or grid search. Other, like `keyword_only` are just a simple helpers and not strictly required.

Assuming you have defined following mix-ins for mean parameter:

```
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Estimator, Model, Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, stddev_samp


class HasMean(Params):

    mean = Param(Params._dummy(), "mean", "mean", 
        typeConverter=TypeConverters.toFloat)

    def __init__(self):
        super(HasMean, self).__init__()

    def setMean(self, value):
        return self._set(mean=value)

    def getMean(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.mean)
```

standard deviation parameter:

```
class HasStandardDeviation(Params):

    standardDeviation = Param(Params._dummy(),
        "standardDeviation", "standardDeviation", 
        typeConverter=TypeConverters.toFloat)

    def __init__(self):
        super(HasStandardDeviation, self).__init__()

    def setStddev(self, value):
        return self._set(standardDeviation=value)

    def getStddev(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.standardDeviation)
```

and threshold:

```
class HasCenteredThreshold(Params):

    centeredThreshold = Param(Params._dummy(),
            "centeredThreshold", "centeredThreshold",
            typeConverter=TypeConverters.toFloat)

    def __init__(self):
        super(HasCenteredThreshold, self).__init__()

    def setCenteredThreshold(self, value):
        return self._set(centeredThreshold=value)

    def getCenteredThreshold(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.centeredThreshold)
```

you could create basic `Estimator` as follows:

```
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable 
from pyspark import keyword_only  

class NormalDeviation(Estimator, HasInputCol, 
        HasPredictionCol, HasCenteredThreshold,
        DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, predictionCol=None, centeredThreshold=1.0):
        super(NormalDeviation, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    # Required in Spark >= 3.0
    def setInputCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`inputCol`.
        """
        return self._set(inputCol=value)

    # Required in Spark >= 3.0
    def setPredictionCol(self, value):
        """
        Sets the value of :py:attr:`predictionCol`.
        """
        return self._set(predictionCol=value)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, predictionCol=None, centeredThreshold=1.0):
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)        
        
    def _fit(self, dataset):
        c = self.getInputCol()
        mu, sigma = dataset.agg(avg(c), stddev_samp(c)).first()
        return NormalDeviationModel(
            inputCol=c, mean=mu, standardDeviation=sigma, 
            centeredThreshold=self.getCenteredThreshold(),
            predictionCol=self.getPredictionCol())


class NormalDeviationModel(Model, HasInputCol, HasPredictionCol,
        HasMean, HasStandardDeviation, HasCenteredThreshold,
        DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, predictionCol=None,
                mean=None, standardDeviation=None,
                centeredThreshold=None):
        super(NormalDeviationModel, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)  

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, predictionCol=None,
                mean=None, standardDeviation=None,
                centeredThreshold=None):
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)           

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        x = self.getInputCol()
        y = self.getPredictionCol()
        threshold = self.getCenteredThreshold()
        mu = self.getMean()
        sigma = self.getStddev()

        return dataset.withColumn(y, (dataset[x] - mu) > threshold * sigma)
```

*Credits to [Benjamin-Manns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234944/benjamin-manns) for the [use of DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52467470) available in PySpark >= 2.3.0*

Finally it could be used as follows:

```
df = sc.parallelize([(1, 2.0), (2, 3.0), (3, 0.0), (4, 99.0)]).toDF(["id", "x"])

normal_deviation = NormalDeviation().setInputCol("x").setCenteredThreshold(1.0)
model  = Pipeline(stages=[normal_deviation]).fit(df)

model.transform(df).show()
## +---+----+----------+
## | id|   x|prediction|
## +---+----+----------+
## |  1| 2.0|     false|
## |  2| 3.0|     false|
## |  3| 0.0|     false|
## |  4|99.0|      true|
## +---+----+----------+
```

Comment: thanks! so a state of an Estimator is considered a parameter as well?

Comment: Do you mean tuned parameters of the estimator as a Param for Model? If so, it is convenient to design this way but it is not a hard requirement for a basic implementation.

Comment: Ok, any hope to get some advice about how to persist custom steps like this?

Comment: This is a very useful example. But what if your transformer/model has parameters that are specific to it rather than the estimator? How do you pass such parameters to the model once it's a stage within a pipeline? I don't want to pass these parameters into the estimator first when they have nothing to do with the estimator. I've asked this question [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642867/how-to-set-parameters-for-a-custom-pyspark-transformer-once-its-a-stage-in-a-fi)

Comment: Thanks @zero323 - is there any update on this? I hate this syntax where you need to inherit from each Param (an Estimator is not a Param so it should not inherit from it...)

Comment: @HananShteingart Both `Estimator` and `Transform` as well as other constructs (like Evaluators) are Params (`issubclass(Estimator, Params)` - note plural not singular as Param is related but different entity), and any built-in Estimator is a subclass of Params. This is direct translation of Scala API which follows the same structure (see [known subclasses](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params)). This is directly tied to `MLRead[er|able]` / `MLWriter[er|able]` interfaces and design of Pipeline API (primarily setters and getters.)

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @Shteingarts Solution, as he creates members on class level and even mixes them with instance ones. Will lead to issues if you create several HasMean instances. Why not use the imho correct approach with instance variables? Same holds for the other code samples.

```
from pyspark.ml.pipeline import Estimator, Model, Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import avg, stddev_samp


class HasMean(Params):
    def __init__(self):
        super(HasMean, self).__init__()
        self.mean = Param(self, "mean", "mean", typeConverter=TypeConverters.toFloat)

    def setMean(self, value):
        return self.set(self.mean, value)

    def getMean(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.mean)
```