# Custom transformer in Pyspark ML

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to write a custom Estimator to fit into Pipeline using Pyspark 1.6.0, so I try the solution in [How to Roll a Custom Estimator in PySpark mllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270446/how-to-roll-a-custom-estimator-in-pyspark-mllib)

It works on Spark 2.0, but when I remove the TypeConverter parameter(which only exists in Spark 2.0) to test it Spark 1.6.0, it shows error:

```
ValueError: Param Param(parent='undefined', name='centered_threshold', doc='centered_threshold') does not belong to NormalDeviation_4dc98930f6cd0fd37ce6.
```

I'm not allowed to use Spark 2.0 in production. How can I change this code to make it work on Spark 1.6.0?