# Spark custom estimator including persistence

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pipeline, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I want to develop a custom estimator for spark which handles persistence of the great pipeline API as well. But as [How to Roll a Custom Estimator in PySpark mllib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270446/how-to-roll-a-custom-estimator-in-pyspark-mllib) put it there is not a lot of documentation out there (yet).

I have some data cleansing code written in spark and would like to wrap it in a custom estimator. Some na-substitutions, column deletions, filtering and basic feature generation are included (e.g. birthdate to age).

- transformSchema will use the case class of the dataset `ScalaReflection.schemaFor[MyClass].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]`
- fit will only fit e.g. mean age as na. substitutes

What is still pretty unclear to me:

- `transform` in the custom pipeline model will be used to transform the "fitted" Estimator on new data. Is this correct? If yes how should I transfer the fitted values e.g. the mean age from above into the model?
- how to handle persistence? I found some generic `loadImpl` method within private spark components but am unsure how to transfer my own parameters e.g. the mean age into the `MLReader` / `MLWriter` which are used for serialization.

It would be great if you could help me with a custom estimator - especially with the persistence part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I believe you're mixing a bit two different things:

- [`Estimators`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#estimators) - which represent stages that can be `fit`-ted. `Estimator` `fit` method takes `Dataset` and returns `Transformer` (model).
- [`Transformers`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#transformers) - which represent stages that can `transform` data.

When you `fit` `Pipeline` it `fits` all `Estimators` and returns `PipelineModel`. `PipelineModel` can `transform` data sequentially calling `transform` on all `Transformers` in the the model.

> how should I transfer the fitted values

There is no single answer to this question. In general you have two options:

- Pass parameters of the fitted model as the arguments of the `Transformer`.
- Make parameters of the fitted model [`Params`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#parameters) of the `Transformer`.

The first approach is typically used by the built-in `Transformer`, but the second one should work in some simple cases.

> how to handle persistence

- If `Transformer` is defined only by its `Params` you can extend `DefaultParamsReadable`.
- If you use more complex arguments you should extend `MLWritable` and implement `MLWriter` that makes sense for your data. There are multiple examples in Spark source which show how to implement data and metadata reading / writing.

If you're looking for an easy to comprehend example take a look a the `CountVectorizer(Model)` where:

- `Estimator` and `Transformer` [share common `Params`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L37).
- Model vocabulary [is a constructor argument](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L182), model [parameters are inherited from the parent](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L182).
- Metadata (parameters) is [written](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L293) an [read](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L305) using `DefaultParamsWriter` / `DefaultParamsReader`.
- Custom implementation handles data (vocabulary) [writing](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L294-L295) and [reading](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.scala#L306-L310).

Comment: Merely extending DefaultParamsReadable and DefaultParamsWritable give java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: read(). Examples seem to use DefaultParamsWriter and DefaultParamsReader, but they are marked as private[ml] and can't be used in custom transformers. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Paul Doesn't sound like you do. By contract to read / write stage you need `MLReadable[_]` / `MLWritable[_]`, which need accompanying `MLReader[_]` / `MLWriter[_]` to satisfy their `read` and `write` methods.

Comment: Do you know of a good example of this. Every example I can find involves DefaultParamsReader and DefaultParamsWriter both of which are private[ml] making them inaccessible to me.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses the **Scala API** but you can easily refactor it to Python if you really want to...

First things first:

- **Estimator**: implements `.fit()` that returns a Transformer
- **Transformer**: implements `.transform()` and manipulates the DataFrame
- **Serialization/Deserialization**: Do your best to use built-in Params and leverage simple `DefaultParamsWritable` *trait* + *companion object* extending `DefaultParamsReadable[T]`. a.k.a Stay away from MLReader / MLWriter and keep your code simple.
- **Parameters passing**: Use a common trait extending the `Params` and share it between your Estimator and Model (a.k.a. Transformer)

Skeleton code:

```
// Common Parameters
trait MyCommonParams extends Params {
  final val inputCols: StringArrayParam = // usage: new MyMeanValueStuff().setInputCols(...)
    new StringArrayParam(this, "inputCols", "doc...")
    def setInputCols(value: Array[String]): this.type = set(inputCols, value)
    def getInputCols: Array[String] = $(inputCols)

  final val meanValues: DoubleArrayParam = 
    new DoubleArrayParam(this, "meanValues", "doc...")
    // more setters and getters
}

// Estimator
class MyMeanValueStuff(override val uid: String) extends Estimator[MyMeanValueStuffModel] 
  with DefaultParamsWritable // Enables Serialization of MyCommonParams
  with MyCommonParams {

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): Estimator[MeanValueFillerModel] = defaultCopy(extra) // deafult
  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = schema // no changes
  override def fit(dataset: Dataset[_]): MyMeanValueStuffModel = {
    // your logic here. I can't do all the work for you! ;)
   this.setMeanValues(meanValues)
   copyValues(new MyMeanValueStuffModel(uid + "_model").setParent(this))
  }
}
// Companion object enables deserialization of MyCommonParams
object MyMeanValueStuff extends DefaultParamsReadable[MyMeanValueStuff]

// Model (Transformer)
class MyMeanValueStuffModel(override val uid: String) extends Model[MyMeanValueStuffModel] 
  with DefaultParamsWritable // Enables Serialization of MyCommonParams
  with MyCommonParams {

  override def copy(extra: ParamMap): MyMeanValueStuffModel = defaultCopy(extra) // default
  override def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = schema // no changes
  override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {
      // your logic here: zip inputCols and meanValues, toMap, replace nulls with NA functions
      // you have access to both inputCols and meanValues here!
  }
}
// Companion object enables deserialization of MyCommonParams
object MyMeanValueStuffModel extends DefaultParamsReadable[MyMeanValueStuffModel]
```

With the code above you can Serialize/Deserialize a Pipeline containing a MyMeanValueStuff stage.

Want to look at some real simple implementation of an Estimator? [MinMaxScaler](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/MinMaxScaler.scala)! (My example is actually simpler though...)

Comment: working off your example I get java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: read() when I try to load the model. What am I not understanding in your example?