# How to set parameters for a custom PySpark Transformer once it's a stage in a fitted ML Pipeline?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I've written a custom ML Pipeline `Estimator` and `Transformer` for my own Python algorithm by following the pattern shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37279526/1843329).

However, in that example all the parameters needed by `_transform()` were conveniently passed into the Model/Transformer by the estimator's `_fit()` method. But my transformer has several parameters that control the way the transform is applied. These parameters are specific to the transformer so it would feel odd to pass them into the estimator in advance along with the estimator-specific parameters used for fitting the model.

I can work around this by adding extra `Params` to the transformer. This works fine when I use my estimator and transformer outside of an ML Pipeline. But how can I set these transformer-specific parameters once my estimator object has been added as a stage to a Pipeline? For example, you can call `getStages()` on a `pyspark.ml.pipeline.Pipeline` and can therefore get the estimators, but there is no corresponding `getStages()` method on `PipelineModel`. I can't see any methods for setting parameters on the `PipelineModel` stages either.

So how can I set the parameters on my transformer before I call `transform()` on the fitted pipeline model? I'm on Spark 2.2.0.

Comment: Ah. I've just spotted [`PipelineModel.transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.PipelineModel.transform) takes optional parameters so I'll look into that...

Comment: Using `PipelineModel.transform()` I can't see how to target the parameters supplied in the `params` argument to my stage in the pipeline. I can't reference an estimator instance because remember my parameters only exist in the transformer, which I can't access!

Comment: I definitely don't want to add transformer-specific params to the estimator because they have nothing to do with the estimator. Also, a given model, once trained, can be used many times to generate predictions in different ways some time later.

Comment: The only thing (hack!) I can think of is to have the estimator keep a reference to the model once it's been fitted. Then you can access that model from the estimator and set whatever parameters you want on it. This would also solve the problem of being able to pass parameters that can't be inherited from `Params` into the transformer, such as a `SparkSession` to be used for creating a `DataFrame`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643152/how-to-create-a-spark-dataframe-inside-a-custom-pyspark-ml-pipeline-transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `getStages()` method on `PipelineModel` but the same class does have an [undocumented member](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.2.0/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py#L189) called `stages`.

For example, if you've just fitted a pipeline model with 3 stages and you want to set some parameters on the second stage, you can just do something like:

```
myModel = myPipelineModel.stages[1]
myModel.setMyParam(42)
# Or in one line:
#myPipelineModel.stages[1].setMyParam(42)

# Now we can push our data through the fully configured pipeline model:
resultsDF = myPipelineModel.transform(inputDF)
```

Comment: TypeError: 'Param' object does not support indexing