# How to create a Spark DataFrame inside a custom PySpark ML Pipeline _transform() method?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

In Spark's [ML Pipelines](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-pipeline.html#how-it-works) the transformer's `transform()` method takes a Spark `DataFrame` and returns a `DataFrame`. My custom `_transform()` method uses the DataFrame that's passed in to create an RDD before processing it. This means the results of my algorithm have to be converted back into a DataFrame before being returned from `_transform()`.

So how should I create the DataFrame from the RDD inside `_transform()`?

Normally I would use [`SparkSession.createDataFrame()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame). But this means passing a `SparkSession` instance, `spark`, into my custom `Transformer` somehow (or a `SqlContext` object). And this in turn can create [other problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642867/how-to-set-parameters-for-a-custom-pyspark-transformer-once-its-a-stage-in-a-fi) such as when trying to use the transformer as a stage in an ML Pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's as simple as doing this inside `_transform()`:

```
yourRdd.toDF(yourSchema)
```

The schema is optional. I wish I could give you a link to `toDF()` but it doesn't seem to be included under https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD for some reason. Perhaps it's an inherited method?

I also previously tested passing a `SparkSession` object into my `Transformer` and calling `createDataFrame()` on it. It works but it's unnecessary.