# How can one develop a custom model with pyspark ml?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How do I create a custom model in pyspark?

In scikit-learn it is easy (see [Rolling your own estimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator)).

However, in pyspark I cannot find any similar documentation.

I found out, from reading the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/ml/base.py), that there are three relevant base interfaces: Model, Estimator and Transformer

However, it is not clear to me if I should inherit from Model or Estimator or both. Especially the inheritance from Parameters is complicated.

I've seen a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270446/how-to-roll-a-custom-estimator-in-pyspark-mllib) but it is almost one year old and I guess things have changed since then. It also seems to refer to mllib and not ml version of spark.

Comment: mllib is spark https://spark.apache.org/mllib/

Comment: @David , there are two ml packages: mllib and ml for spark: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38835829/whats-the-difference-between-spark-ml-and-mllib-packages

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. Depending on your use case, it seems like you could potential use a transformer or an estimator. A "model" is chain  (pipeline) of transformations and potentially an estimation. See for some more details https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-pipeline.html

Comment: your link does not explain how to create your own estimator.