# Transformer operating on multiple features in pyspark.ml

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I want to make my own transformer of features in a `DataFrame`, so that I add a column which is, for example, a difference between two other columns. I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml), but the transformer there operates on one column only. `pyspark.ml.Transformer` takes a string as an argument for `inputCol`, so of course I can not specify multiple columns.

So basically, what I want to achieve is a `_transform()` method that resembles this one:

```py
def _transform(self, dataset):
    out_col = self.getOutputCol()
    in_col = dataset.select([self.getInputCol()])

    # Define transformer logic
    def f(col1, col2):
        return col1 - col2
    t = IntegerType()

    return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(f, t)(in_col))
```

How is this possible to do?

Comment: Could it be that `HasInputCols` (plural) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by first creating a `Vector` out of the set of features that I want to operate on, and then applying the transform on the newly generated vector feature. Below is an example code of how to make a new feature which is a different of two other features:

```
class MeasurementDifferenceTransformer(Transformer, HasInputCol, HasOutputCol):  

    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
        super(MeasurementDifferenceTransformer, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self.__init__._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCol=None, outputCol=None):
        kwargs = self.setParams._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = dataset[self.getInputCol()]

        # Define transformer logic
        def f(vector):
            return float(vector[0] - vector[1])
        t = FloatType()

        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(lambda x: f(x), t)(in_col))
```

To use it, we first instantiate a `VectorAssembler` to create the a vector feature:

```
pair_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["col1", "col2"], outputCol="cols_vector")
```

Then we instantiate the transformer:

```
pair_transformer = MeasurementDifferenceTransformer(inputCol="cols_vector", outputCol="col1_minus_col2")
```

Finally we transform the data:

```
pairfeats = pair_assembler.transform(df)
difffeats = pait_transformer.transform(pairfeats)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to go through all these trouble in order to operate on multiple columns. Here's a better approach using HasInputCols (instead of HasInputCol)

```
class MeasurementDifferenceTransformer(Transformer, HasInputCols, HasOutputCol):  
    @keyword_only
    def __init__(self, inputCols=None, outputCol=None):
        super(MeasurementDifferenceTransformer, self).__init__()
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        self.setParams(**kwargs)

    @keyword_only
    def setParams(self, inputCols=None, outputCol=None):
        kwargs = self._input_kwargs
        return self._set(**kwargs)

    def _transform(self, dataset):
        out_col = self.getOutputCol()
        in_col = self.getInputCols()

        # Define transformer logic
        def f(col1, col2):
            return float(col1-col2)
        t = FloatType()

        return dataset.withColumn(out_col, udf(lambda f, t)(*in_col))
```

Comment: This solution worked for me after I removed "lambda" from the return line (not sure if it's because I'm using Spark > 3.0?)