# How to create a custom tokenizer in PySpark ML

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

```
sentenceDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame([
        (0, "Hi I heard about Spark"),
        (1, "I wish Java could use case classes"),
        (2, "Logistic,regression,models,are,neat")
    ], ["id", "sentence"])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words") 
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame)
```

if I run command

```
tokenized.head()
```

I would like to get result like this

```
Row(id=0, sentence='Hi I heard about Spark',
    words=['H','i',' ','h','e',‘a’,……])
```

However,now the result is that

```
Row(id=0, sentence='Hi I heard about Spark',
    words=['Hi','I','heard','about','spark'])
```

Is there any way to achieve this by Tokenizer or RegexTokenizer in PySpark？

similar questions is here：[Create a custom Transformer in PySpark ML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [pyspark.ml documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer). `Tokenizer` only splits by white spaces, but `RegexTokenizer` - as the name says - uses a regular expression to find either the split points or the tokens to be extracted (this can be configured by the parameter `gaps`).

If you pass an empty pattern and leave `gaps=True` (which is the default) you should get your desired result:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="sentence", outputCol="words", pattern="")
tokenized = tokenizer.transform(sentenceDataFrame)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please accept the answer if your problem was solved?

Comment: Sure. Have a happy day