# TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'function'>

Tags: pyspark, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

Can I combine sparknlp with pyspark? I have a data (of tweets) consists of two category features "keyword" and "location", and one free textual "text". I am trying to build a a sentence embeddings using GoogleUniversalSentenceEncoder, and add two one hot encoders. This is my code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, OneHotEncoder, VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector, VectorUDT
from sparknlp.base import DocumentAssembler
from sparknlp.annotator import UniversalSentenceEncoder

# Define the pipeline stages
stages_one_hot = []

# Define the categorical columns
categorical_cols = ["keyword", "location"]

for col in categorical_cols:
    indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol=col, outputCol=col+"_index")
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol=col+"_index", outputCol=col+"_vec")
    stages_one_hot += [indexer, encoder]

stages_text = []
# Add the DocumentAssembler stage
documentAssembler = DocumentAssembler().setInputCol("text").setOutputCol("document")
stages_text += [documentAssembler]

# Add the UniversalSentenceEncoder stage
encoder = UniversalSentenceEncoder.pretrained().setInputCols(["document"]).setOutputCol("sentence_embedding")
stages_text += [encoder]

# Define the UDF to convert the sentence_embedding column to DenseVector type
# denseVectorizer = udf(lambda x: DenseVector(x.toArray()), VectorUDT())

# Add the DenseVector conversion stage
# denseVector = denseVectorizer(col("sentence_embedding")).alias("sentence_embedding_dense")
denseVectorizer = udf(lambda x: DenseVector(x.toArray()), VectorUDT())
stages_text += [denseVectorizer]

stages_together = []
# Add the VectorAssembler stage
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=[col+"_vec" for col in categorical_cols] + ["sentence_embedding_dense"],
                            outputCol="features")
stages_together += [assembler]

# Add the LogisticRegression stage with the target column as the label
lr = LogisticRegression(featuresCol="features", labelCol="target")
stages_together += [lr]
    
    # Create the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages_one_hot + stages_text + stages_together)

df = trainDataset

# Fit the pipeline to the data
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)

# Apply the pipeline to the data and get the predictions
transformed_df = pipelineModel.transform(df)
```

However, I always get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot recognize a pipeline stage of type <class 'function'>.
```

I tried to google everything and talk to chatGPT also, it always brings me to the same point. Is it possible to make this feature extraction and build a model?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you try taking stages out of the pipeline to isolat the cause - is it the udf causing the error? If so, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50075806/how-to-add-udf-in-pyspark-pipeline

Comment: I had already tried to remove the later parts of the pipe and the problem disappears (only onehot), but when I add universal_sentence_encoder the problem re-occurs. It looks like the problem is indeed in the UDF. But still I can't figure out from the link you sent what I should do. 
I try: 
stages_text += [SQLTransformer(
    statement="SELECT sentence_embedding_dense FROM __THIS__")]

all I get is: 
AnalysisException: Column 'sentence_embedding_dense' does not exist

Comment: In the SQLTransformer you need to change the statement to the SQL you need for your transformation. But your case is probably more complex - you might need to follow the first approach - creating a custom transformer. Try this question as an alternative - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415784/how-to-add-my-own-function-as-a-custom-stage-in-a-ml-pyspark-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The problem was in the type of GoogleUniversalSentenceEncoder(). It isn't a vector as expected. But a list of 1 element dictionary that contains metadata and the vector. Therefore the next UDF should solve the problem:

```
stages_together = []
convert_to_vector_udf = spark.udf.register(
    "convert_to_vector_udf",
    lambda r : Vectors.dense(r[0][5]), 
    VectorUDT()
)

stages_text += [SQLTransformer(
    statement = "SELECT *, convert_to_vector_udf(sentence_embedding) sentence_embedding_densed FROM __THIS__")]
```

However working with ClassifierDLApproach will now be forbiden because it is tuned to work with the classic GoogleUniversalSentenceEncoder()