# Best way to Create a custom Transformer In Java spark ml

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, transform, apache-spark-mllib

I am learning Big data using Apache spark and I want to create a custom transformer for Spark ml so that I can execute some aggregate functions or can perform other possible operation on it

Comment: You can be inspired and adapt the answer for PySpark from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml

Comment: @bonnal-enzo I am new to big data and really not getting this how to do and even not getting and sample or any example in java that how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extends **org.apache.spark.ml.Transformer** class, this is an abstract class so you have to provide implementation of abstract methods.
As I have seen that in most of the cases we needs to provide implementation of **transform(Dataset<?> dataset)** method and  implementation of **String uid(**) .
Example:

```
public class CustomTransformer extends Transformer{

 private final String uid_;

 public CustomTransformer(){
  this(Identifiable.randomUID("Custom Transformer"));
 }

 @Override
 public String uid(){
  return uid_;
 }

@Override
public Transformer copy(ParamMap extra){
  return defaultCopy(extra);
}

@Override
public Dataset<Row> transform(Dataset<?> dataset){
 // do your work and return Dataset object
}

@Override
public StructType transformSchema(StructType schema){
  return schema;
}
```

}

I am also new in this so I suggest you should learn what are the uses of these abstract methods.

Comment: Ok sure I will try it